# Binary tree java

Tags: java, input, binary-tree, nodes

How to create input from user?
i'm doing a binary tree programming question but i don't know how to make the input come from the user

```
public class BinaryTreeApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

BinaryTree a = new BinaryTree();

Node root = a.createNewNode(10);
root.left = a.createNewNode(12);
root.right = a.createNewNode(15);
root.left.left = a.createNewNode(25);
root.left.right = a.createNewNode(30);
root.right.left = a.createNewNode(36);
```

Comment: Well, you either loop and ask for user input from the console or create a gui

Comment: use java.util.Scanner like shown here https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp

Comment: can you give me an example if it use a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do that, you need to think of some format of input - can be many things.
Just for example the input can be just 'space' separated values
`10 12 15 25 30 26`
and then parse that input and build the tree from that.
wrote some pseudo code for after you parsed the input

```
root = input[0]
queue.enqueue(root)
for i in 1 to input.size step = 2:
    current = queue.dequeue()
    current.left = input[i]
    current.right = input[i + 1]
    queue.enqueue(current.left)
    queue.enqueue(current.right)
```

EDIT:
added some Java code

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class
import java.util.LinkedList; 
import java.util.Queue; 



public class HelloWorld{
    private static class Node{
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        public String value;
        public Node(String v){
            value = v;
        }
    }
     public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        String userInput = "10 12 15 25 30 26 27";
        String[] values = userInput.split(" ");
        Node root = new Node(values[0]);
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<>();
        q.add(root);
        for(int i = 1; i < values.length; i = i + 2){
            Node current = q.remove();
            current.left = new Node(values[i]);
            current.right = new Node(values[i + 1]);
            q.add(current.left);
            q.add(current.right);
        }

     }
}
```